# How do we express "hidden bad surprises" in correct English?

Tags: expressions

I would like to say something in the sense of

> Someone who includes on purpose bad surprises or traps in their product.

The topic of the text is about honesty and I want to highlight that people should avoid the above. Is there an expression for this in English?

Comment: Do you mean a commercial product? I can't imagine what kind of thing you have in mind.

Comment: Yes. I mean if all people were honest in everything they did (including their work), things would be much better.

Comment: Aren't bad surprises always hidden or at least not visible?

Comment: One "commercial product" that comes to mind here is [*Monty Python's **Spring Surprise***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puNT08o6jyE) :) But (unlike the stereotypical sausage maker) the Python's confectioner was completely honest about the ingredients of his "Crunchy Frog" sweetie!

Comment: Are you asking for a term for the "bad surprises" or for the person (bad actor, snake oil salesman) putting them there?

Comment: A [booby trap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/booby%20trap) would be a word for the bad surprise, but I think the OP is asking for a person. I can't find "booby trapper" in dictionaries, but you might use it anyway.

Comment: ... *it’s a great piece of software but there are a few **gotchas** in there if you don’t know what you’re doing.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The part that that I always liked was the ***lightly killed***.

Comment: @Showsni I'm asking whether there is an expression implying "deceiving". But I think I can use a simple sentence with booby trap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly look at these 3 answered questions. Though not exact duplicates, you will find many useful words in the answers.

[Something appears valuable or precious but it isn't, symbolically equivalent to Pyrite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/595484/397404)

[Common phrases for something that appears good but is actually bad](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/71398/397404)

[Word or saying for something that isn't as good as people say it is](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/272660/397404)

I especially liked "snake oil", "hollow bunny" and "embellished"

Comment: Thank you Banuyayi. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

"The fine print" is a way of saying "nasty surprise". It refers to a clause or disclaimer written into a contract,  usually in tiny text, that is likely to be displeasing or unacceptable to the potentially agreeing party.

"Had I read the fine print I would not have been taken advantage of."

"You'd better read the fine print before you agree to marry that man."